# preamble is not working after updating packages: graphicspath not working

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, beamer

I have enjoyed r-markdown for creating beamer presentations and often use a preamble. The `preamble.tex` file I use includes several packages and statements, such as `setmainfont` (Korean) and `graphicspath`.

Unfortunately, there were two issues that appeared after updating all packages in RStudio recently. 
1: My code created beamer slides as usual, but failed to display Korean language. 
2: The (relative) path I defined in `\graphicspath{}` did not work any more.

The use of Korean fonts can be fixed by adding `mainfont` in the YAML. However, because `graphicspath` is not applied to `include_graphics()`, I guess the preamble.tex is not working. It might be issues related to bugs or version across packages or platforms. 
I would appreciate it if anyone can help me figure out what the problem is so that I can fix those issues.

I just uploaded a reproducible example [here](https://github.com/samhyunyoo/test).

The error message I got is as below.

> Error in knitr::include_graphics("testimage.png") : 
>     Cannot find the file(s): "testimage.png"
>   Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->  실행이 정지되었습니다

My session info is as below:
sessionInfo()

> R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Korean_Korea.949  LC_CTYPE=Korean_Korea.949
>   [3] LC_MONETARY=Korean_Korea.949 LC_NUMERIC=C                 [5]
>   LC_TIME=Korean_Korea.949
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] knitr_1.28
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] compiler_3.6.2 
>   htmltools_0.4.0 tools_3.6.2     yaml_2.2.1       [5] Rcpp_1.0.3
>   rmarkdown_2.1   digest_0.6.24   xfun_0.12        [9] rlang_0.4.4
>   evaluate_0.14

Comment: Can you include the `.log` file? BTW, generally it is preferred to have a [mre] included in the question instead of on some other side. Where would you expect Korean language in your example?

Comment: Hi Ralf, I just added an error message I got to the original post and also updated the example by adding a few lines to test Korean language to the existing Rmd file. The `include_graphics()` generates a prompt error because `graphicspath()` does not work.